# mxmlc java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type Actionscript-3 Papervision3D Flash Develop

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxmlc, papervision3d

I've been compiling my Papervision3D actionscript project using mxmlc using the following command line parameter:

```
mxmlc.exe -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true source.as
```

The following error is displayed:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

The software runs fine in Flash CS3 without embed commands:

```
[Embed(source="/Textures/Texture.png")]
private var TextureClass:Class;
```

etc., but I do need the assets embedded.

Building in Flash Develop gets the same error of course, and won't produce a .swf. However it still says the .swf size is/would be 25MB.

I haven't compiled many projects in mxmlc (or Flash Develop) but my last one was fine with all embedded assets showing.

HELP!  Have you seen this error?  How can I get rid of it?

I would offer a bounty on this one, but my score is too low. :/

Comment: What embed commands are you referring to?  How are you embedding assets?  Are you using a library, such as for Papervision3D?  Why isn't the sw specified as part of your command line?  Is the library SWC compiled with the same version of the Flex compiler that the main project is?

Comment: I mean the embed statements in the code:

Comment: '[Embed(source="Textures/Texture.png")]
public var TextureClass:Class;'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got rid of the java error, but I found out why I was getting a white screen on the .swf!

It was a stack trace error.

I got rid of this error by adding compiler argument:

```
-omit-trace-statements=false
```

Now my .swf runs fine!

Still don't know what is causing the java ZipException, looks like a problem with one of the .png graphics files, but I can't see a problem in the .swf.

Because of the ZipException the project won't compile in Flash Develop, so I am left with using mxmlc.